# how can I impute NA with row wise mean in a dataframe

Tags: r

```
data <- tibble(
name = c("Carl","Josh","Laura"), 
wt_Tuesday_5pm = c(100, 150, 140),
wt_Wednesay_3pm = c(104, 155, 138),
wt_Friday_9m = c(NA, 160, 142)
)
```

This is my tibble.
It has one NA ,
How can I impute NA with row wise mean ( i mean , calculate mean of 100 and 104 and impute that mean at NA )

Comment: the units is in Lbs (wt_Tuesday_5pm wt_Wednesay_3pm wt_Friday_9m)
 how I convert to KG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R option using `apply` :

```
data[-1] <- t(apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE);x}))
data

#   name  wt_Tuesday_5pm wt_Wednesay_3pm wt_Friday_9m
#  <chr>          <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 Carl             100             104          102
#2 Josh             150             155          160
#3 Laura            140             138          142
```

Comment: the units are in pound (wt_Tuesday_5pm wt_Wednesay_3pm wt_Friday_9m)
, how can I convert into KG ?

Answer (score 3):

We get the `rowMeans` of the numeric columns, create a logical matrix based on NA elements, use that index to assign the replicated vector of row means

```
v1 <- rowMeans(data[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
i1 <- is.na(data[-1])
data[-1][i1] <- v1[row(data[-1])][i1]
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  name  wt_Tuesday_5pm wt_Wednesay_3pm wt_Friday_9m
#  <chr>          <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 Carl             100             104          102
#2 Josh             150             155          160
#3 Laura            140             138          142
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we can use `coalesce` after creating a column of `rowMeans`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
   mutate(Mean = rowMeans(select(., where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
         across(c(where(is.numeric), -Mean), ~ coalesce(., Mean)), 
         Mean = NULL)

data
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  name  wt_Tuesday_5pm wt_Wednesay_3pm wt_Friday_9m
#  <chr>          <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 Carl             100             104          102
#2 Josh             150             155          160
#3 Laura            140             138          142
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` from the Tidyverse to do this. The coalesce function will replace NA values with the row mean:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(rowMean = rowMeans(select(., -name), na.rm = T),
         across(starts_with("wt"),
                ~ coalesce(., rowMean))) %>%
  select(-rowMean)
```